# Wrong Minimum frequency Core i7 CPU

Tags: cpu, cpufreq, scaling, frequency

The problem with my Linux machine is, the frequency reported by the files `cpuinfo_min_freq` and `scaling_min_freq` show `1200000` but in Windows it can be slowed down to `900000`.

This causes my Laptop to be extra hot compared to Windows.

Here's my `/proc/cpuinfo:`

http://termbin.com/w08a

How can I bring this value lower ? Obviously editing the file won't work.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add the output of this to your question: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`

Comment: I'm using acpi-cpufreq as scaling driver, although it's the same with intel_pstate (tested). The point is, scaling driver looks at something to get the minimum frequency which can't be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have been able to determine 12 is the minimum pstate for your processor (or 1200000 KHz).
You can check for yourself by reading the `MSR_PLATFORM_INFO` register and parsing the bits yourself. Here is an example for my processor, where my minimum pstate is 16:

```
$ sudo modprobe msr
$ sudo rdmsr --bitfield 47:40 -d -a 0xce
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
```

What windows is doing, I wouldn't know.
As for your heat issues, I doubt that minimum clock frequency is the root issue. Have a look at graphics power consumption.

Comment: This command gave me 12 (as expected). I've turned off my AMD graphics in BIOS just to save power and lower the temperature.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using the Intel P-state CPU frequency scaling governor, according to the driver documentation (Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt):

"For contemporary Intel processors, the frequency is controlled by the
processor itself and the P-State exposed to software is related to
performance levels.  The idea that frequency can be set to a single
frequency is fictional for Intel Core processors. Even if the scaling
driver selects a single P-State, the actual frequency the processor
will run at is selected by the processor itself."

So I doubt you will have any mileage in changing these frequencies, it's left to the processor nowadays.

Comment: I don't think the intel_pstate CPU frequency driver is being used. Why not? Because the CPU frequencies numbers in the /proc/cpuinfo listing are a nice round numbers, something that almost never occurs with the intel_pstate driver and always occurs when using the acpi_cpufreq CPU scaling driver (because the intel_pstate driver lists actual frequencies over the last sample interval and the acpi-cpufreq driver lists the frequency (pstate actually) that was asked for). Anyway, rather than debate the point, I'll add a comment asking the OP for the information.

Comment: I'm not using intel_pstate. Although I've been testing it and it gives the same result. Because both scaling governors look at the same info to determine what is the minimum frequency for a CPU. That's where the problem is